# NodeJs - Mock external call with stub

Tags: node.js, sinon, stub

I am currently testing a controller (let's call it sut in my code) which call an other controller (let's call it OtherController) in a method.

I have a test as below

```
it('My Test', () => {
  const stub = sinon.stub(OtherController, 'externalMethod').returns([OK, data]);
  sut.method();
  expect(stub.called).to.be.true;
})
```

But this code is not working, I get an error

> [TypeError: _get__(...).externalMethod is not a function]

It worked when I didn't care about what the method should retrun with

```
const stub = sinon.stub().returns();
sut.__Rewire__('OtherController', stub);
```

But I'm unable to make it work when I want a specific return from the OtherController.externalMethod.

How should I proceed ?

Comment: In your second code block instead of `stub` you have `sut`

Comment: The second block is working in an other test. I created a stub to substitute to my OtherController with the second line. So it's normal to have sut, it's my tested controller

Comment: have you checked for typos that might give 'externalMethod' a variable name?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Is there a variable with a name similar to the method that you're calling in your controller

Comment: No, there is not such a variable

Comment: @Tibo can you post the minimum amount of code for `sut` and `OtherController`?